# Filepond and webp images

Tags: webp, filepond

I'm using filepond with jpeg and png files and all works well. The page show an image that can be deleted or substituted. If I update the image with jpeg or png files, the image is correctly updated, stored on the server and display in the filepond "preview". If I update the image with webp image, all work the same, but, if I reload page the webp image loaded with **files** property, will not be showed. What's wrong?

I've tried full image path, relative image path, different image type.
The filepond drop with webp image always display 1kb size.

Comment: Are you sure that the server supports serving WebP files? check if the server is configured to serve WebP files with the correct MIME type. Additionally, verify that the image path is correct and accessible.

Comment: Yes, if I drop a WebP file on the filepond droplet, the preview is ok, if I write directly the image path in the browser, the image is displayed correctly, I have the problem only with "preloaded/preadded" image in filepond.

Comment: Ok, solved... apache2 on debian bullseye doesn't add the correct content type. I've added `AddType image/webp .webp` in the mime.conf and now, all works well.

Comment: Yea this is what I already said above. Want me post it as answer?